# Serre's theorem

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Suppose that $R$ is a root system in a complex $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with a base $S = \{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$, and that $$(n(\alpha_i,\alpha_j))_{\alpha_i,\alpha_j \in S}$$ is the Cartan matrix of $R$ with respect to $S$.

Serre's theorem is the following:

> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra defined by the $3n$ generators
>   $X_i,Y_i,H_i$ ($i = 1...n$), and the relations
>
> 1. $[H_i,H_j] = 0$,
> 2. $[X_i,Y_i] = H_i$, and $[X_i,Y_j] = 0$ if $i \neq j$,
> 3. $[H_i,X_j] = n(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)X_j$, and $[H_i,Y_j] = -n(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)Y_j$,
> 4. $Ad_{X_i}^{\:(-n(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)+1)}(X_j) = 0$ if $i \neq j$,
> 5. $Ad_{Y_i}^{\:(-n(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)+1)}(Y_j) = 0$ if $i \neq j$.
>
> Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, where the subalgebra
>   generated by $H_i$ is a Cartan subalgebra, and its root system is $R$.

I would like to clarify two things. Firstly, I think that if $R$ were an irreducible root system, then it follows that $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple. Is this true?

Secondly, if it is true that $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple in the case that $R$ is irreducible, does this follow directly from Serre's theorem, or other results? How do we deduce that $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple if $R$ is irreducible, as opposed to just semisimple?

Comment: First question: yes, then the Lie algebra is simple. Second question: via Dynkin diagram (connected=simple).

Comment: @Dietrich, how do we conclude that a connected Dynkin diagram gives rise to a simple Lie algebra? I understand that the classification tells us that, but I'm under the impression that to go from a connected Dynkin diagram to a semisimple (simple) Lie algebra, I first construct the Cartan matrix, and then use the above. At what point am I able to prove that my Lie algebra is simple?

Comment: You are able to prove it once you go back. If the Lie algebra decomposes, then this gives a corresponding decomposition of the root system (and hence of the Dynkin diagram).

Comment: For an overview of the classification result, see my note http://pure.au.dk/portal/da/publications/the-classification-of-semisimple-lie-algebras(04c29758-17a5-4a7a-8f8e-df9bc6ee805b).html